# C# linq Array to dictionary with respective indexes as a list/array in value

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find out the best approach for my use case.
What I would like to have is a Dictionary with Vector3 as keys and respective indexes from the array of those vectors3.

So given:
Vertex[] vertices <- each vertex contain position (vector3) and are in sequence in the array (at a given index which is important)

Some of the indexes (Vertices) in that array can share the same possiton and I would like to group them by that position with respecitve indexes they're in the array.

```
public class MyClass {
  public Vector3 position;

  public MyClass(Vector3 position) { this.position = position; }
}

MyClass[] vertices = {
      new MyClass(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)),
      new MyClass(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)),
      new MyClass(new Vector3(2, 0, 2)),
      new MyClass(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)),
      new MyClass(new Vector3(2, 0, 2)),
      new MyClass(new Vector3(3, 0, 2)),
    };

var groupedSharedVertices = vertices
 .Select((vertex, i) => new {index = i, position = vertex.position})
 .GroupBy(vert => vert.position);

groupedSharedVertices[3].ToList().ForEach(x=> Debug.Log(x));
```

This works but doesn't give me the data I would like it to be:

> { index = 3, position = (0.5, 0.0, 0.5) }
>
> { index = 6, position = (0.5, 0.0, 0.5) }
>
> { index = 9, position = (0.5, 0.0, 0.5) }
>
> { index = 12, position = (0.5, 0.0, 0.5) }

Instead, I would like to have:

> { (0.5, 0.0, 0.5): (3, 6, 9, 12) }

Is there some nice way to achieve this output?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also include the input that should produce the desirable output? As I can see the question contains only an undesirable output and a desirable output, with no corresponding input.

Comment: `vertices.Select((vertex, i) => new {index = i, position = vertex.position}).GroupBy(vert => vert.position).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList() /* or ToArray()*/)`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thought is clear from the context but updated question with respective code.


DDomen hmm this still gives me the position in the value whre I need only the indexes in value and vector3 in the key

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var groupedSharedVertices = vertices
    .Select((x, i) => new { vert = x, index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.vert.position)
    .ToList();

groupedSharedVertices
    .ForEach(x => 
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key} : ({string.Join(", ", x.Select(x => x.index))})"));
```

Output:

```
<0, 0, 0> : (0, 1, 3)
<2, 0, 2> : (2, 4)
<3, 0, 2> : (5)
```